# boost::bind or boost::lambda on std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, boost

Suppose I want to use std::lower_bound on a std::vector of pointers like this:

```
struct X {
    int x;
    double y;
};

// overloads for normal comparisons
bool operator< (int left, const X& right) { return left < right.x; }
bool operator< (const X& left, int right) { return left.x < right; }

std::vector<X*> v;

int searchValue = 5;
std::vector<X*>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), searchValue,
    ? // what the heck do I put here?
);
```

Would I use boost::bind or boost::lambda here, and if so, how?

I would think it would be like this:

```
std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), searchValue, searchValue < *_1);
```

However I get an illegal indirection error on this.

Comment: Boost.Lambda is officially deprecated since the release of [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/) v3, so the _real_ answer is to use Boost.Phoenix. I.e., the code you have works fine with Boost.Phoenix without any changes (except that the arguments to your `operator<` are backwards).

Comment: Ordinarily I'd say `std::less<X>()` but you're comparing `int` with `X` so that won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still on boost 1.43, so Boost.Phoenix is not available :(

Comment: That being the case, correct your `operator<` (or overload it) and use Boost.Lambda. :-]

Comment: Or if you plan on using C++11 anyways use the build in lambda functionality: `[](X* a, int val){ return *a < val; }` if I read your code correctly

Comment: Also, I'd rather not have to define a specific overloaded operator either to keep the overloaded operators to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after some trial and error. Boost.Bind won't work here and the compiler will get confused on with placeholder to use. Boost.Bind uses _1 in an anonymous root namespace. Boost.Lambda uses it under the namespace boost::lambda::_1.

Also, I had the order wrong with the comparisons.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

// ...

std::vector<X*>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), searchValue,
    *boost::lambda::_1 < searchValue
);
```

Comment: However, VS 2008 complains when you change X* to boost::shared_ptr<X>. Not sure what's up with that. VS 2010 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
struct MyLessThan
{
   bool operator()( const X* xVal, int iVal )
   {
      return xVal->x < iVal;
   }
};

std::vector<X*> v;

int searchValue = 5;
std::vector<X*>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), searchValue, MyLessThan() );
```

That should work.

Comment: Nope, needs pointer argument to `operator()`, because the `std::vector` stores pointers.

Comment: @Xeo :) I hadn't noticed that it was a vector of pointers. It also had another error. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: This will work, but I was hoping to avoid defining a custom predicate. It would be cleaner to use boost::bind or lambdas.